# Hangfire recurring job doesn't start immediately

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am using cron expression for creating a recurring job. I am creating expression to execute every half an hour on 3 days of a week .
The execution is correct but the time it starts is not correct. 
Suppose the creation of job  happens at 2 : 16 pm,  the job starts executing at 2 : 30 pm .
If I configure to execute 2 : 20 also the job starts at 2 : 30 pm which ideally I wanted to start at 2 : 20 and recur every half an hour .
Currently I am not finding a way to start at 2 : 25 and recur every half an hour.

Can someone please let me know why is it happening when used a cron expression ? Is there a way to identify this pattern so that I can adjust my execution time. 
The cron expression is "*/30 * * 1,2 1,2,3"

@cocowalla: I am using sql server as the backend. I am replicating  connection string exactly the way it is given in hangfire documentation but not looked at polling.  Is there any other reason apart from this?

Comment: Can you add the cron expression that you're working with, without it we can only speculate.

Comment: IIRC, how accurate job timings are depends on how often the storage backend is polled. Which storage backend are you using, and have you looked at the config for this?

Comment: How about `16,46 * * * 1,2,3`. You can use [this site](https://crontab.guru/#16/30_*_*_1,2_1,2,3) to help you. You already have the correct cron to run the expression every 30 minutes, you juste need to start the first one at 16 min.

Comment: FYI your cron run only in January and Frebruary as is. This is due to the `1,2` in the months.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html), the SQL backend is polled, so start time accuracy may be limited:

> One of the main disadvantage of raw SQL Server job storage implementation – it uses the polling technique to fetch new jobs. Starting from Hangfire 1.7.0 it’s possible to use TimeSpan.Zero as a polling interval, when SlidingInvisibilityTimeout option is set.

````
{
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<name or connection string>", options);```
````